# There is ESLint rule to avoid try-catch if there just one line?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Let's say I have this code:

```
export class a {

    private async func(){

        try {
            await something();
        } catch (error) {
          /////
        }

    }
}
```

I want to avoid the use of try-catch when there is only one line in the try block and instead use catch like this:

```
await something().catch(err => {…});
```

There is any ESLint rule that will raise an error for that?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

I tried to use the `no-restricted-syntax` rule with my `@typescript-eslint/parser` according to the AST, but it does not work:

```
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
      "error",
      {
        "selector": "TryStatement > BlockStatement[body.length=0]",
        "message": "No try block for one line!"
      }
    ],
```

Comment: You can probably do this via https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax - I'm not sure what AST you'd use though.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson My parser is `@typescript-eslint/parser`. So, I tried to use it, but it does not work (take a look on my edit in the original post).

Comment: *Just thinking:* But you can use .catch only on promises... What if in the try-catch there's only for example `parseInt('ABC')`?  In that case you need a try-catch with one line in the try block. Wouldn't a [catch-or-return](https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/catch-or-return.md) rule be better?  If interest, the library is [eslint-plugin-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-promise)

Comment: @Doc Good point. The try-catch block can also handle non-async code, so I can check with `no-restricted-syntax` if there is an `AwaitExpression` in this line and then raise an error to use catch instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following selector:

```
 "selector": "TryStatement > BlockStatement[body.length=1] AwaitExpression"
```

This will catch any try statement which has a block with only one child node that includes an await expression.

If you want to be less specific you can just remove the "AwaitExpression" to catch any try statement with only a single line.